# Show sums of complex $\sin$ and $\cos$ series

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

By considering the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^ne^{in\theta}$ for $0<r<1$ show that

$$\sum_{n=1^\infty}r^{n}\cos(n\theta)=\frac{1-r\cos(\theta)}{1-2r\cos(\theta)+r^2} \text{ and } \sum_{n=1}^\infty r^n\sin(n\theta)=\frac{r\sin(\theta)}{1-2r\cos(\theta)+r^2}$$

My first thought is to use the exponential identities for $\sin$ and $\cos$ but I haven't seen that getting me much of anywhere. Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can explicitly find the value of the first series, I presume. Then use Euler's formula to relate it to the other two series.

Comment: Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Infinite_geometric_series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}r^ne^{in\theta}
&=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(re^{i\theta})^n\\
&=\frac{1}{1-re^{i\theta}}\\
&=\frac1{(1-r\cos\theta)-ir\sin\theta}\\
&=\frac{1-r\cos\theta+ir\sin\theta}{1-2r\cos\theta+r^2}\\
&=\frac{1-r\cos\theta}{1-2r\cos\theta+r^2}
+i\frac{r\sin\theta}{1-2r\cos\theta+r^2}\\
\end{align*}

Then observe that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}r^ne^{in\theta}
=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}r^n\cos n\theta+i\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}r^n\sin n\theta
$$

Now real and imaginary parts must be equal so you get the conclusion.

Note that we was allowed to use the geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}q^n=\frac1{1-q}$ since $|re^{i\theta}|=r\in]0,1[$.

Comment: That should have been obvious. Thanks!